# Django redirect for multilingual website

Tags: python, django, http-redirect

I'm working on a bilingual website French and English, and I'm trying to figure out how to detect and redirect the French users to index_fr.html (in templates folder).

My urls.py (it only shows the english ver. for now):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', profiles.views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Do you want the URL to change for french users or just the template? Have you enabled [`LocaleMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)? If so, your `request` object has a `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` property that you can check in your view.

Comment: Or just add a "^(<language_code>[a-z]+)/" type parameter to all your URLs...

It's not clear from your question what the existing framework of the website looks like and therefore what would be an appropriate solution?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.

As dhke said, I enabled LocalMiddleware and used request.LANGUAGE_CODE to write a function in views.py that renders a template depending on the language and it works!:

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):

context={}
if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr':
    template='index_fr.html'
else:
    template='index_en.html'

return render(request,template,context)

def fr(request):

context={}
template='index_fr.html'
return render(request,template,context)

def all(request):

context={}
template='index_en.html'
return render(request,template,context)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns =[
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

url(r'^$', profiles.views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^index_fr.html', profiles.views.fr, name='fr'),
url(r'^index_en.html', profiles.views.all, name='all'),
```

]